# Android SQLite when no result

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm using the databaseutils to run a SQL query on my database. Basically just a login, however  I want to take the userid of the person who's logged in so i'm selecting that. It works fine if theres a result, but falls over when theres no result. If there a way to set if is set or similar?

```
    if(String.valueOf(loginCount).equals("2")) {

    File dbfile = new File(Global.StaticDB + "/Users" ); 
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);

    String loginQueryCheck=(String)DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(db,"SELECT UserID from Users where Username like '" + txtUsername.getText().toString() + "' AND Password like '" + txtPassword.getText().toString() + "'",null);

    Log.e("Login Query:", loginQueryCheck);
    db.close();  

    if(loginQueryCheck.length() > 1) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Logged In";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    Intent ShowMainPage = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainPage.class);
    startActivityForResult(ShowMainPage, 0);
    } else {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Login Failed";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    }
    }
```

Comment: what if my name is `Selvin'; DROP TABLE USERS;--`? http://xkcd.com/327/ ... anyway if there is no results return `null` from `DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery` and then check if `loginQueryCheck` is `null`

Comment: Thanks for this. It's okay about protection, luckily it's an internal app. If it was external i'd be protecting. Thanks - Tom

Comment: What happens if you wrap the stringForQuery in a catch block - is any exception thrown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the check to:

```
if(loginQueryCheck != null && !loginQueryCheck.equals("") && loginQueryCheck.length() > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to count UserID instead query UserID in your SQL statement.

```
int loginQueryCheck=(int)DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(db,
      "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) FROM Users WHERE Username like '" +
      txtUsername.getText().toString() + "' AND Password like '" +
      txtPassword.getText().toString() + "'",null);
```